# What is the time complexity for this Algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

```
for i = 1 to n do
    j = 2
    while j < i do
        j = j * j
```

I think it's time complexity is : log(n!) = n * log(n).

but solution said that it is : n * loglog(n) and I didn't understand why?

Comment: You will do n * sqrt(n) operations, so the complexity is n^(3/2)

Comment: @Fabinout That is not correct. Why do you think you do sqrt(n) operations for the inner loop?

Comment: @Fabinout If this inner loop multiplied by two every time it would be n log n, this is even faster, n*sqrt(n) is way off track

Comment: @adao7000 you start at 2, then 4, then 16, then 256. So you're right, and I'm wrong, this wasn't a sqrt complexity.

Comment: Consider: What is the value of `j` after `M` steps? (Hint: nothing involving a `!`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the explanation below, I assume that all arithmetic and comparison operations are O(1).

```
for i = 1 to n do
```

The below is repeated N times, which makes the `n *` part in the solution.

```
    j = 2
    while j < i do
        j = j * j
```

The above calculates the first number of the following sequence that's `>= i` :

```
2 = 2^(2^0)
4 = 2^(2^1)
16 = 2^(2^2)
256 = 2^(2^3)
65536 = 2^(2^4)
...
```

So the only thing you need to do is to find the relation between i and 2^(2^i). And `log(log(2^(2^i))) = log(2^i) = i`.

Comment: Excellent explanation!

Comment: Good answer, it's important to note that the outer loop is just there to complexify the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Let's break it down and work from the inside out.

Imagine the following:

```
j = 2
while j < n do
  j = j * 2
```

`j` goes 2, 4, 8, 16..., so if `n` doubles in size, it only takes roughly one more iteration for `j` to surpass it.  That's basically the definition of logarithmic.

The inner loop in your case is a bit different:

```
j = 2
while j < n do
  j = j * j
```

Now `j` goes 2, 4, 16, 256, 65536... and surpasses `n` even more easily.  In the first case, `j` was growing exponentially per iteration, now it's growing doubly exponentially.  But we're interested in the inverse--`j` surpasses `n` in log(log(`n`)) steps.

Then the outer loop just means you do that `n` times.